# Firebase Deploy Error 'Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object undefined]?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am getting this error when `Firebase deploy` in terminal. I can't find any of my code with `Route.post()` in. It looks like it s being called from a module ...

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as post] (/Users/Desktop/castApp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as post] (/Users/Desktop/castApp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:482:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/castApp/functions/index.js:12:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Comment: First, make sure your CLI is fully up to date.  If it is still not deploying, contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks for taking time. CLI (both Terminal and VS are up to date). Looks like a debug question is out of scope for Firebase support ... or did I miss something?

Comment: If there's a problem deploying, then support should at least know about it, so they can collect information and see if others are having the same problem.  It doesn't hurt to fill out the form.

Comment: thanks I will try it ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurred when I deleted the function in the controller file but didn't update the corresponding place where needs this function as a callback function in the router file - index.js.

index.js:

```
app.post('/new', addNew);

const { addStandupHost } = require('./APIs/candidates');
```

candidate.js:

```
// exports.addNew = (request, response) => {
   //    ...
   //     db operation here
   //     ...
   //}
```

It was solved just by deleting the corresponding code in index.js. To avoid this error, we should keep functions export and import consistent.